# Numpy returning False even though both arrays are the same?

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, ipython, numpy-ndarray

From my understanding of numpy, the `np.equal([x, prod])` command compares the arrays element by element and returns True for each if they are equal. But every time I execute the command, it returns False for the first comparison. On the other hand, if I copy-paste the two arrays into the command, it returns True for both, as you can see in the screenshot. So, why is there a difference between the two?

[image]

Comment: You cannot compare floating-point numbers, as they are only an approximation. My guess is that you need to use some function which checks if they're equal given a small enough delta value.

Comment: When you compare them by hardcoded values, they will be equal as they are approximated in the exact same way. But once you apply some mathematical operation on them, it's no longer possible to check if two floating-points are equal.

Comment: Quick example: https://onlinegdb.com/B1SO-l_H8

Comment: So, if I want to compare the results, do I have to convert them to integer values first? Why do the commands return floating point numbers and not integers in the first place?

Comment: You could do that, or you compare them against a small delta. The reason you get a floating-point is that most mathematical operations require floating-point values, like the square root, dot product, matrix inverse and more.

Comment: By using a small delta, I mean comparing that two values are equal or just a really small value apart. Check this out: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: Or `np.allclose` if you do not need to return the mask.

Comment: Okay now I understand. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Great. I'll compile these comments to an answer so it can be marked as resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot compare floating-point numbers, as they are only an approximation. When you compare them by hardcoded values, they will be equal as they are approximated in the exact same way. But once you apply some mathematical operation on them, it's no longer possible to check if two floating-points are equal.

For example, this

```
a = 0

for i in range(10):
    a += 1/10
    
print(a)
print(a == 1)
```

will give you `0.9999999999` and `False`, even though (1/10) * 10 = 1.

To compare floating-point values, you need to compare the two values against a small delta value. In other words, check if they're just a really small value apart. For example

```
a = 0

for i in range(10):
    a += 1/10
    
delta = 0.00000001
print(a)
print(abs(a - 1) < delta)
```

will give you `True`.

For numpy, you can use [numpy.isclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to get a mask or [numpy.allclose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) if you only want a True or False value.